# How to convert media image object to bitmap using android.hardware.camera2 package?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I want to convert an image object that I got from  ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener to bitmap .

I have read a lot of articles and a lot of solution but nothing works with me .

when I have tried to getPixelStride() from the plane then the values is zero ??
I don't know why .
also getRowStride() return zero

```
Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                int mWidth = image.getWidth();
                int mHeight = image.getHeight();

                final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
             final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                int offset = 0;
               int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                // create bitmap\


                image.close();

                CapturedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                CapturedImage.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

can't create the bitmap where the stride is zero

also when trying to

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
         buffer.get(bytes);
       image.close();
```

CapturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);

then I got an error message that not enough to copy pixel

Comment: You might want to consider using a [camera library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created), such as Google's [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera), rather than struggling with the native camera API directly.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare but i dont have time to change to camerax now

Comment: @CommonsWare .. Im going to use camera x ... but how i can get external camera lens .. i dint know how to do that ... its not like camera 2 api .. getcameralist